# Find email location in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-email

We recently migrated to Google Apps for business, many users using the MS Outlook Sync tool to sync between the mail client and Google.

I have a user that was in the Gmail interface and dragged-and-dropped a folder and now can't find it.  The user remembered one of the subject lines, so we searched for it and were able to find it.  The problem is, the email doesn't have any indication of where it is "filed" (no labels), and I need to find the rest of the emails that were associated with this folder.

I've checked all obvious places like Inbox, Trash, Important, etc.  I've also looked on the Outlook side which was no help.

Is there a way to determine email location once found in a search?

Comment: There are no folders in gmail, only labels.

Comment: Do you remember the folder's name?

Answer (score 3):

There's no real concept of "location" in Gmail (or Google Apps Email), since Gmail uses labels, not folders.

When you search and there are no labels on the conversations that come up, that means that the only "label" being used is "All Mail" (and that's not really a label).

While knowing one subject line can help you find one conversation, it's not going to help you find other conversations that had that old, now gone, label.

Google Apps Email *might* have some logs that might be useful (but I doubt it).

More than likely you're just going to have to search to find (most) of the missing messages. Fortunately, Gmail has lots of [search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190), so combining `to:user@example.com` with things like `after:2010/05/15 before:2010/05/01` and whatever else you can think of will help narrow things down. `has:nouserlabels` will also be useful in finding the messages that are lacking labels (and probably shouldn't).

At least they're likely not lost, just hiding in a large haystack. At the very least, if one of the conversations gets responded to it will jump right into the Inbox label (and can then be properly labeled).

Answer (score 0):

The email must be archived and will be present under the "All Mails" view folder.